# How to stop jquery function to continue to repeat if option reselected

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I've been stuck on trying to fix this bug for the last couple days and cant seem to find a fix anywhere would love some help or a link that will describe how to get past this issue. I'm sure there is an easy way to do this and I am just over complicating it.

I just want to be able to display a price on an item once two options have been clicked from two different selects.

This is what I have so far which does the job fine the first time around however when it's reselected or another option is clicked the first option doesn't disappear.

```js
jQuery(function($){
   $("select[name='type'], select[name='size']").change(function(){
      var select = $(this);
      if(select.val() === "50x25" && "Canvas"){
          $("<input>").attr({ name: "defindex", placeholder: "$150", readonly: "readonly" , class: "abc"}).appendTo(select.parent());
      }
      else if(select.val() === "125x125" && "Canvas"){
          $("<input>").attr({ name: "defindex", placeholder: "test", readonly: "readonly" , class: "abc"}).appendTo(select.parent());
      }
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control" name="type" style="width:25%;">
  <option>Type</option>
  <option value="Canvas">Canvas</option>
  <option value="Framed Print">Framed Print</option>
  <option value="Acrylic">Acrylic</option>
</select>

<select class="form-control" name="size" style="width:25%;">
  <option>Size</option>
  <option value="50x25">50x25</option>
  <option value="125x125">125x125</option>
  <option value="500x250">500x250</option>
</select>
```

I am aware of the `isset` feature within PHP but that only seems to work if i click another button which just looks tacky.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: I thunk $(this) returns only the changed object. You have to get two values one by one using id selector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following code:

```js
jQuery(function($){
   $("select[name='type'], select[name='size']").change(function(){
      var select = $(this);
      var $input = select.parent().find('input');
      if($input.length === 0){
        $input = $('<input>');
      }
      if(select.val() === "50x25" && "Canvas"){
          $input.attr({ name: "defindex", placeholder: "$150", readonly: "readonly" , class: "abc"}).appendTo(select.parent());
      }
      else if(select.val() === "125x125" && "Canvas"){
          $input.attr({ name: "defindex", placeholder: "test", readonly: "readonly" , class: "abc"}).appendTo(select.parent());
      }
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control" name="type" style="width:25%;">
  <option>Type</option>
  <option value="Canvas">Canvas</option>
  <option value="Framed Print">Framed Print</option>
  <option value="Acrylic">Acrylic</option>
</select>

<select class="form-control" name="size" style="width:25%;">
  <option>Size</option>
  <option value="50x25">50x25</option>
  <option value="125x125">125x125</option>
  <option value="500x250">500x250</option>
</select>
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: It shows same $150 even if you select 'Acrylic' or 'Framed Print'.

Comment: Can you please let me know that which value you need to show on the 
value of select1 and select2.
I mean, Canvas & 50x25 -> $150. You need to add the condition in the code.

Comment: I used the same input box instead of appending another one.

Comment: One more question any idea how i could add text to the $input.attr area instead of using placeholder, so i could add the text to a database?

Comment: You can use $('input').attr(your_attr_name, text).

Comment: dont full understand how to implement that, im guessing something like this $input.attr({ text: "defindex"?